# Randomly assign values in data frame based on a weightage percentage

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

For example I have the following data frame

```
ID     A/B Test
1234
3456
6789
3987
```

I want to randomly assign a "Y" or "N" to the A/B Test column based on 50% distribution. In other words I want to split the df and make sure 50% of the records have a "Y" and 50% a "N", but these values should be assigned **randomly**.

Output DataFrame:

```
ID     A/B Test
1234   Y
3456   N
6789   N
3987   Y
```

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.random.choice`:

```
df['A/B Test'] = np.random.choice(['Y','N'], size=len(df))
```

Note that this works if your data is sufficiently long, and you will have **roughly** the same amount of `Y` and `N`. That is, you may have 9995 `Y` and 10005 `N`.

Comment: To get exactly 5000 Ys and 5000 Ns, you might do something like `l = ['Y'] * (len(df) / 2) + ['N'] * (len(df) / 2); random.shuffle(l)` and then assign this list as the new series.